# Understanding the Difference Between Logger and LoggerConfig in Log4J2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I was reading through the Log4J2 manual and had some clarifying questions about Logger vs LoggerConfig.

In a `log4j2.xml` file, why do `<Logger>` elements refer to LoggerConfig configurations rather than Logger configurations? Specifically, on the [Log4J2 configuration page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), it mentions

> A LoggerConfig is configured using the `<Logger>` element. The logger element must have a name attribute specified, will usually have a level attribute specified and may also have an additivity attribute specified.

This, however, seems particularly confusing given that both the Logger and LoggerConfig classes exist in the software architecture. Why isn't `<LoggerConfig>` used then instead of `<Logger>`?

Also, one additional question - on the [Log4J2 architecture page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html), it mentions

> A Logger that is directly linked to the root LoggerConfig can be obtained as follows: `Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);`

but according to the UML diagram on the top of the page there is a 1 to many association between LoggerConfig and Logger. Thus, how can you get a single Logger by specifying the root LoggerConfig name?

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't `<LoggerConfig>` used then instead of `<Logger>`?

I agree that the naming is confusing, and I'm not sure exactly why `Logger` was used instead of `LoggerConfig`. My guess would be that it was done as a way to try to simplify the config file since you will never configure a `Logger` object (`LogManager` does this for you) there is no need to distinguish between `Logger` and `LoggerConfig` in the configuration file itself so it was shortened to `Logger`.

> how can you get a single Logger by specifying the root LoggerConfig
>   name?

I believe the answer to your question lies in the hierarchical nature of loggers. You can have multiple `Logger` instances sharing the same `LoggerConfig`. Consider the situation where you define a `LoggerConfig` (using `Logger` element in the config file) with a package name, e.g. `com.my.package`. Let's say that you have multiple classes in this package which all obtian a `Logger` via the `LogManager` by either explicitly or implicitly passing their full class name. So maybe you have a class `com.my.package.Class1` and another called `com.my.package.Class2`. Since you defined a `LoggerConfig` for `com.my.package` but not for `com.my.package.Class1` (or `Class2`) both classes will get their own `Logger` instance but both `Logger`s have the same `LoggerConfig`. This is also illustrated in examples 3 and 4 on the [log4j2 architecture page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html).